# How to create security group ingress dynamically in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating a security group that has some standard ingress rules. I also want to add additional ingress rules based on a variable.

```
variable "additional_ingress" {
  type = list(object({
    protocol    = string
    from_port   = string
    to_port     = string
    cidr_blocks = list(string)
  }))
  default = []
}


resource "aws_security_group" "ec2" {
  name        = "my-sg"
  description = "SG for ec2"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.this.id

  egress {
    to_port     = 0
    from_port   = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  } 

  # rdp
  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 3389
    to_port     = 3389
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  }

  # additional ingress rules
  ingress {
    for_each    = var.additional_ingress
    protocol    = each.value.protocol
    from_port   = each.value.from_port
    to_port     = each.value.to_port
    cidr_blocks = each.value.cidr_blocks
  }
}
```

I am getting error

> A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it
> unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the
> value in its "for_each" expression. │ Remove this reference to
> each.value in your configuration to work around this error.

How do I add ingress rules based on variable

Answer (score 4):

This is most easily managed with the `aws_security_group_rule` resource and the `for_each` meta-argument:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ec2" {
  for_each = var.additional_ingress

  type              = each.value.type
  from_port         = each.value.from_port
  to_port           = each.value.to_port
  protocol          = each.value.protocol
  cidr_blocks       = each.value.cidr_blocks
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ec2.id
}
```

Note that the variable declaration for `additional_ingress` is missing the `type` key in its `object` constructor definition, so that would need to be added:

```
variable "additional_ingress" {
  type = list(object({
    type = string
    ...
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Comment: This can cause conflicts if the SG defines ingress and you have SG rules resources too. Personally if the OP is defining ingress in the SG I would just use the dynamic block https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic blocks like this:

```
dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each    = var.additional_ingress
    protocol    = ingress.value.protocol
    from_port   = ingress.value.from_port
    to_port     = ingress.value.to_port
    cidr_blocks = ingress.value.cidr_blocks
  }
```

Provided the `additional_ingress` is an object (map) of ingress entries.

Of course, I would advise to use `aws_security_group_rule` [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule), but if this is already live project, I understand if you'd want to stay with inline rules. Have fun!